# Which was the comic where the Joker wanted to marry Batgirl?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, the-joker, batgirl

Trying to identify the comic where Joker wanted to marry Batgirl.

Was it really the Joker or someone else pretending to be Joker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only such comic I know of is a part of the *Death of the Family* story arc. The exact issue appears to be *Batgirl* vol. 4 #14 (2013), but the whole marriage affair spanned from #14 to #16.

[image: Cover image - #14][image: Cover image - #15][image: Cover image - #16]
<sub>(Click for full resolution)</sub>

It is indeed Joker himself; after cutting off his face and taking a leave from Gotham, he returns to abduct most of the Bat-family to torment Batman.

He does propose to Batgirl, but their wedding ceremony is cut short by an unexpected guest.

> [image: Proposal]
> <sub>(Click for full resolution)</sub>

Comment: That's a disgusting cover...

Comment: @Mithrandir no, that's the last page. They wouldn't dare muck up their age rating with such a cover

Comment: Ah, whatever...